# Rear Mech Too Far Forward

Tags: derailleur-rear, mechanical

I recently crashed my road bike in the city on some tram tracks, a terrible experience and don't recommend. I came off the bike and the bike itself landed on its right hand side and sustained damage on the handlebars, shifter, pedal & rear mech. The rear mech hangar was bent, I had one spare so I put that on and redid the cable and tried to set it back up. I was having trouble getting the damaged mech to work for all gear ranges, the top jockey wheel was hitting the chainstay unless turned all the way in, previously it was about halfway out. At this point I called the rear mech toast and ordered a new one.

The new mech fitted fine and soon I had the bike setup and riding again. Today I went to do a turbo session and take the back wheel off. I was unable to get the cassette past the top jockey wheel and no amount of adjustment to the mech could get it off. This does sound noobish but I've removed the rear wheel hundreds of times and know to put the bike in the biggest gear, remove the thru axle, push down on the rear mech and the wheel will just fall out. This is not the case and the rear mech looks really tilted far forward. The b-limit screw is almost all the way in just to stop the top jockey wheel from rubbing on the frame.

I've taken some pictures of the rear mech, I'm wondering if i've somehow caused damage to the frame. It is carbon so its game over if I have, will be taking it to a shop but kind of want to know beforehand if its just me being an idiot or a bigger problem with the bike.

A middle gear, looks very weird
[image: In a random gear]

The big dog again, the spring is visibly under tension when before it wasn't
[image: The big dog mk2]

The b-limit screw is turned all the way in and it has about 5mm of travel before the jockey wheel hits the frame. Is something wrong here?

Edit: the part I replaced the mech with is exactly the same, same with the rear hangar. I've added a side by side to show this
[image: Side by side]

The bike is a **Specialized Roubaix Comp 2018**

Comment: Note that carbon is among the easiest bike materials to repair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using https://specializedconceptstore.co.uk/content/products/2018-roubaix-comp_12182.jpg   a zoom of the mech shows that the angle of the mech is wrong.  Since that is not a sprung joint like the darker bolt nearest the cable entry, then there will be teeth on the rear holding whatever angle you set.  Back off the middle 10mm bolt, reposition the mech, and tighten.

The angle/arc of the cable housing will be a good guide for relative positioning.  Yours is almost a full 180 degree turn, whereas stock it was just over a 90 degree.

[image]

Comment: +1 to this. See here for more info on [direct mount derailleurs](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/technologies/component/details/direct-mount-rear-derailleur.html)

Comment: I bought the Ultegra R8000 Long Cage Rear Mech which is the same part as before. I actually have been having the exact same problem with the old mech, I can't seem to position it backwards enough. Perhaps I need to move the linkage backwards rather than have it straightened out

Comment: Added a picture to show the link was on the old mech

Comment: @Axemasta sounds like you had two problems - an initial setup one where the angle was a bit wrong, which was then compounded by the crash.  Good work keeping the old mech for spares - it could be that would be functional if the linkage angle was correct initially.

Comment: I had a spare replacement mech hangar on standby since I had a very similar crash at the start of 2020 and the guy at the shop saved the mech but told me to get a new hangar. So all the parts have been replaced, I’ve inspected the frame and there’s no visible cracking or even impact marks, would a bent frame play in this situation?

Comment: There’s no teeth. There should be a little tab on the B link that needs to contact the protrusion on the hanger.

Comment: @MaplePanda There are little teeth, I've placed it in the middle but obviously i needed to be more extreme in the positioning. I'll have it up on the workstand tonight and hopefully have it back to its full glory!

Comment: @Criggie thanks for the advice, I feel really dumb the old mech works perfectly! I can't believe the parts needed to fit together like that, I completely just assumed the little divets in the rear mech aligned centrally onto the hangar. Bikes all fixed, shifting is crisp & i can get the back wheel off 

Comment: @Axemasta on the upside, you now have a spare.  In these days of C19 and troubled supply lines, getting bike parts can be hard.  You're just pre-prepared !

Comment: @Criggie the true upside is that I now don't have a scuffed rear mech for my Instagram photos ;) I crashed it on an icy winter commute at the start of 2020 and its a scar i've had to long show the world! And of course I'm not waiting for parts :)